# AndEngine - Supporting Multiple Screens

Tags: android, andengine

I'm using the latest version of AndEngine and I'm trying to make a game compatible with all type of screen resolutions. Is this code going to to that? If no, what I'm supposed to do to accomplish that?

```
@Override
public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions()
{
   camera = new BoundCamera(0, 0, GameWidth, GameHeight);
   EngineOptions engineOptions = new EngineOptions(true,ScreenOrientation.PORTRAIT_FIXED, new FillResolutionPolicy(), this.camera);
   engineOptions.getAudioOptions().setNeedsMusic(true).setNeedsSound(true);
   engineOptions.setWakeLockOptions(WakeLockOptions.SCREEN_ON);
   return engineOptions;
}
```

Comment: It's not an easy task. Read on a tutorial: http://android.kul.is/2013/10/andengine-tutorial-dealing-with-screen-sizes.html

Answer (score 1):

Using SVG extension with FillResolutionPolicy works for some, You can also maintain resolution vs. resources on the various devices to create a set of graphics assets for a couple of base resolutions and either scale up or down depending on the device being run on.

Here are some links that maybe useful to you

http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles2/targeting-multiple-display-resolutions-t6794.html

http://android.kul.is/2013/10/andengine-tutorial-dealing-with-screen-sizes.html

www.matim-dev.com/most-important-concepts.html

Answer (score 0):

Most difficult part for the different screen ratios. If you want to achive that without stretching your artifacts you need to use a bigger background than needed. Thats what i do... I use a bigger background but do not show anything important on the sides. This way 4:3 screens see all the background, 16:10 screens sees less but doesnt miss any important info... and everybody is happy